# Running a job on Heroku, continuously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm creating a Twitter app in Rails which I'm hosting on Heroku.

For my app I have a background job that needs to continuously search Twitter.

Unfortunately it seems like Cron jobs can only run at max once per hour, but this wont do for my app I'm afraid. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Even better would be if I could use the TweetStream gem and have a connection open to Twitter all the time. But I'm suspecting there may be even greater difficulties with this. Am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: ps. Another strategy I'm considering is to setup an EC2 instance on which I run two services. One which monitors Twitter with the TweetStream gem and inserts any found tweets into a database, and a second one which queries the database for new tweets and pushes them to the Heroku app. Is this a better solution? ds.

Comment: I'm in the same situation! One way would be to use workers, with a single worker that inserts a new (identical) job when it finishes one. You'd have to add some kind of rate limiting and it's still a bit clunky. Did you come up with something better?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku supports DelayedJob to run background processes...

And for the fee:
"Workers are charged at the same rate as Dynos: $0.05 per hour, prorated to the second. Unlike Dynos, Workers are starting with the first worker. For example, an application with 3 workers for 3 hours will be charged $0.15 for each hour the workers are running."

http://docs.heroku.com/delayed-job